# I do not want to show all the default option list on click the datalist input box

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

On click the input field, I do not want to display or show all the options or list. I just want to display while inputting some text only.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <body>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <label for="browser">Choose your country:</label>
     <input list="browsers" name="browser" id="browser">
     <datalist id="browsers">
      <option value="Australia">
       <option value="USA">
       <option value="Inda">
       <option value="Bhutan">
       <option value="Thailand">
       <option value="Canada">
       <option value="Japan">
       <option value="China">
       <option value="France">
       </datalist>
       </body>
       </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an `input` event listener that adds the `list` attribute when the user types in the field. The `id` of the `datalist` can be stored in a data attribute.

```js
$('input').on('input', function(){
  const input = $(this)
  if(input.val().length > 0){
     input.attr('list', input.data('list'));
  } else {
     input.removeAttr('list');
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <label for="browser">Choose your country:</label>
  <input data-list="browsers" name="browser" id="browser">
  <datalist id="browsers">
      <option value="Australia">
       <option value="USA">
       <option value="Inda">
       <option value="Bhutan">
       <option value="Thailand">
       <option value="Canada">
       <option value="Japan">
       <option value="China">
       <option value="France">
  </datalist>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```